# Manually Authentication Spring Security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I have a code for manually authentication in spring security as follow:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication));
```

In these code, the field `username` and `password` is the real account in my system.

But it is sensitive to put the real information in the code.

I mean, we create a fake account and grant them authority such as `USER` or `ADMIN`

**My Question is:**

Is there anyway for manual authentication without using real account.

Comment: username and password are "usernameReal" and "passwordReal", respectively. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just create an `Username... Authentication` with whatever username and password, as long as they are not real, plus the desired authority.

Then put it in the `SecurityContext`.

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin_user", "", authorities);
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Comment: I tried you way but I found a problem as: Cannot set this token to trusted - use constructor which takes a GrantedAuthority list instead